# POX SVCUtil Generated Class Casting

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, xml-serialization, svcutil.exe

I used the SVCUTIL to generate a class form an XSD. I'm having difficulties figuring out how to take the incoming request object and retrieving the "MsgType" value from the object.

I thought by doing this I would be able to access the data simply using:

```
request.Request.MsgType
```

However, it isn't this simple. The only options 'request' gives me is:
Equals
GetHashCode
GetSchema
GetType
Nodes
ReadXML
ToString
WriteXML

Is there some sort of casting I need to do to the serialized object in order to access MsgType?

```
public ServiceProviderTic callRequestFunc(ServiceProviderTic request) {
      //How do I get request.Request.MsgType Value?
}
```

Root Element in generated class:

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

[assembly: System.Runtime.Serialization.ContractNamespaceAttribute("", ClrNamespace="")]

[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "3.0.0.0")]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="RequestType", Namespace="")]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.KnownTypeAttribute(typeof(ResponseType))]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.KnownTypeAttribute(typeof(DateTimeInfoType))]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.KnownTypeAttribute(typeof(OriginType))]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.KnownTypeAttribute(typeof(LocaleInfoType))]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.KnownTypeAttribute(typeof(ProductType))]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.KnownTypeAttribute(typeof(ValueType))]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.KnownTypeAttribute(typeof(AuthInfoType))]
public partial class RequestType : object, System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject
{

private RequestType.MsgTypeType MsgTypeField;

[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(IsRequired=true)]
public RequestType.MsgTypeType MsgType
{
    get
    {
        return this.MsgTypeField;
    }
    set
    {
        this.MsgTypeField = value;
    }
}

 [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="RequestType.MsgTypeType", Namespace="")]
public enum MsgTypeType : int
{
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
    act = 0
}
}

[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "3.0.0.0")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSchemaProviderAttribute("ExportSchema")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(IsNullable=false)]
public partial class ServiceProviderTic : object, System.Xml.Serialization.IXmlSerializable
{

private System.Xml.XmlNode[] nodesField;

private static System.Xml.XmlQualifiedName typeName = new System.Xml.XmlQualifiedName("ServiceProviderTic", "");

public System.Xml.XmlNode[] Nodes
{
    get
    {
        return this.nodesField;
    }
    set
    {
        this.nodesField = value;
    }
}

public void ReadXml(System.Xml.XmlReader reader)
{
    this.nodesField = System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlSerializableServices.ReadNodes(reader);
}

public void WriteXml(System.Xml.XmlWriter writer)
{
    System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlSerializableServices.WriteNodes(writer, this.Nodes);
}

public System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema GetSchema()
{
    return null;
}

public static System.Xml.XmlQualifiedName ExportSchema(System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaSet schemas)
{
    System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlSerializableServices.AddDefaultSchema(schemas, typeName);
    return typeName;
}
```

XML:

```
<ServiceProviderTic>
<Request>
<MsgType>act</MsgType>
```

XSD Schema

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
<xs:element name="ServiceProvideTic" nillable="false">
<xs:annotation>
<xs:documentation></xs:documentation>
</xs:annotation>
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="Version" type="xs:string" nillable="false"/>
<xs:choice>
<xs:element name="Request" type="RequestType" nillable="false"/>
<xs:element name="Response" type="ResponseType" nillable="false"/>
</xs:choice>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:complexType name="RequestType">
<xs:annotation>
<xs:documentation> Request Information</xs:documentation>
</xs:annotation>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="MsgType" nillable="false">
<xs:simpleType>
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
<xs:enumeration value="act"/>
```

Comment: Please post the top part of the class i.e. the lines before private RequestType.MsgTypeType MsgTypeField;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several days of learning and figuring out how to access the data without doing it the old fashion way. Here is what I have came up with:

Microsoft offers an XSD and SVCUTIL for converting xsd's to classes and making them serializable. The reason I was stuck on this project was because of the complex types, i've never done this before. I used:

Command Prompt:
XSD.exe ServiceProviderTic.xsd /CLASSES

Which generated ServiceProviderTic.cs

I created a web service:

Interface:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate="/MyService", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    XElement callRequestFunc(XElement request);
```

Class:

```
public XElement callRequestFunc(XElement request)
    {
        ServiceProviderTic requestSer = Utility.DeserializeData(request);

        if (requestSer.Item.GetType() == typeof(RequestType))
        {
            RequestType reqObj = (RequestType)requestSer.Item;
            string datapiece = reqObj.MsgType.ToString();
        }

        XElement responseSer = Utility.SerializeData(requestSer);

        return responseSer;
    }
}
```

XElement helped me accept plain old xml (POX) and respond with plain old xml. Below are the helper functions which serialize and deserialize my xelement. I also included extra code which removed namespaces I didn't need.

```
public class Utility
{

    public static ServiceProviderTic DeserializeData(XElement request)
    {
        var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ServiceProviderTic));
        return (ServiceProviderTic)ser.Deserialize(request.CreateReader());
    }

    public static XElement SerializeData(ServiceProviderTic response)
    {
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (TextWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream))
            {
                var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ServiceProviderTic));
                xmlSerializer.Serialize(streamWriter, response);
                return Utility.RemoveAllNamespaces(XElement.Parse(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray())));
            }
        }
    }

    public static XElement RemoveAllNamespaces(XElement source)
    {
        return !source.HasElements
                   ? new XElement(source.Name.LocalName)
                   {
                       Value = source.Value
                   }
                   : new XElement(source.Name.LocalName, source.Elements().Select(el => RemoveAllNamespaces(el)));
    }
}
```

I hope this helps someone in the future!

Answer (score 0):

Check out some good advice [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412178%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on creating REST web services which support both XML and JSON (see the WebHttpBehavior class)

Other than that I'm not sure what to make of your XSD.

Comment: There is no WSDL, just an XSD. Do you have any other suggestions on how to go about casting the xml to a class? or perhaps a better method of accomplishing what i'm looking to do?

Comment: Have you been able to call this web service, and in that case how are you calling it? or are you just looking to deserialize the bit of XML above ? If not who wrote the web service ? The "normal" way of describing a service is through a WSDL. I can see the XSD describes the XML sample but it's not enough to generate a working proxy.

Comment: I'm using Firefox's "Poster" addon to post plain xml data to my webservice. I'm wanting to deserialize the object to retrieve data values from nodes in code "callRequestFunc". I was given the XSD only, I converted the XSD to a class using SVCUTIl, then created a WCF service, but when I post plain XML to the service, I have no idea how to retrieve the values from the nodes.

Comment: So the code above is for the server side part of it all (i.e. the actual web service) ? Sorry I'm trying to get my head around this :)

Comment: Yes, it's the server side part that a client will be posting too.